# Enable Play/Pause on background for a AVPlayer on iOS

Tags: ios, background, audio-streaming, ios7, avplayer

I tried more than 20 alternatives to do that without succeed. This will make me crazy! I just want to play stream audio with AVPlayer on AppDelegate (coz I want to access around in my app), with background audio and the most important, enable the play/pause button on ControlCenter (iOS 7). Can anyone explain me the process or give me a simple code example?

Comment: hi could you find any solution?
I am facing the same problem

Comment: I got the following to work - but not sure it is "officially approved": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457659/reacting-to-controlcenter-events-when-using-avplayer-for-hls-audio-playback